# Is KeyError in dataframe caused incorrect groupby application?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-groupby

I have made a summarized dataframe from another dataframe using `.groupby` and `.agg`.

```
sum_df = cnms_df.groupby(['Tiermetric', 'Mod_unMod', 'Val_Combined', 'Det_Approx', 'State', 'Region', 'CO_FIPS']).agg({'MILES': 'sum'})
```

However, something doesn't look quite right; there seems to be missing values.

```
Tiermetric Mod_unMod Val_Combined Det_Approx State Region CO_FIPS MILES 
Other 1    UnMapped  ASSESSED     Approx     IN    5      18001   8.397255
                                                          18003   3.284817
                                                          18011   64.019156
                                                          18017   9.068318
TIER 4     Modernized VALID       Detailed   NC    4      37119   2.046716
                                             NC    4      37120   59.890107
                                             NC    4      37025   3.773599
```

When I try to do something like this:

```
sum_df['CO_FIPS'][0]
```

I get an error that seems related to indexing:

> KeyError: 'CO_FIPS'

What I want is for my final dataframe to look like this:

```
Tiermetric Mod_unMod Val_Combined Det_Approx State Region CO_FIPS MILES 
Other 1    UnMapped  ASSESSED     Approx     IN    5      18001   8.397255
Other 1    UnMapped  ASSESSED     Approx     IN    5      18003   3.284817                    
Other 1    UnMapped  ASSESSED     Approx     IN    5      18011   64.019156
Other 1    UnMapped  ASSESSED     Approx     IN    5      18017   9.068318
TIER 4     Modernized VALID       Detailed   NC    4      37119   2.046716
TIER 4     Modernized VALID       Detailed   NC    4      37120   59.890107
TIER 4     Modernized VALID       Detailed   NC    4      37025   3.773599
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The groupby and sum cause all of these columns to become a multi-index. You can use `reset_index` to turn the index into columns.

Comment: also, consider passing `as_index=False` in `groupby()`

Comment: That worked! Is there a way to prioritize the order of the groupy? Lets say I want Region, then State, then CO_FIPS, etc...

Comment: thanks @QuangHoang I updated answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The groupby and sum cause all of these columns to become a multi-index. You can use `reset_index()` or pass in `as_index=False` to turn the index into columns.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, 2], 'b':[10, 20, 30]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   a   b
0  1  10
1  1  20
2  2  30

In [4]: grouped = df.groupby('a').agg({'b': 'sum'})

In [5]: grouped  # a is an index now
Out[5]:
    b
a
1  30
2  30

In [6]: grouped = df.groupby('a', as_index=False).agg({'b': 'sum'})

In [7]: grouped  # now a is a column
Out[7]:
   a   b
0  1  30
1  2  30
```

This will work with multi-indexes as well.

Comment: Is there a way to prioritize the order of the columns in groupy? Lets say I want Region, then State, then CO_FIPS, etc.

Comment: yes. change the order of the columns you're passing to the `groupby` function.

Answer (score 0):

Set `as_index` to `False`, by default this will be `True`:

```py
sum_df = cnms_df.groupby(as_index=False,by=['Tiermetric', 'Mod_unMod', 'Val_Combined', 'Det_Approx', 'State', 'Region', 'CO_FIPS']).agg({'MILES': 'sum'})
```